# Getting the Rows Affected by UPDATE in SQLite3 without Extra Query

Tags: c, sqlite, sql-update

Instead of using `SELECT` followed by `UPDATE` in a function I'm calling pretty frequently, is there a way to update rows in an SQLite3 database and get those updated rows without a second query or doing anything else that is slower than `SELECT` followed by `UPDATE`? Using triggers and an intermediate table doesn't count because it would still be slower than what I want. I'm using the standard `sqlite3` C library.

**Example:**

```
UPDATE "ACTIVE"
SET confirmed2 = '%d'
WHERE username2 = '%s' AND activity = '%d'
```

I'm updating the "ACTIVE" table's rows. I also want to retrieve all rows where "username2" and "activity" are a certain pair of values so I can check another column's values, "username1". Since the `UPDATE` command is already querying those rows to update them, there should (but maybe isn't) a way for me to get those rows without making it query again. I can get the *number* of rows affected, but I can't find anything about getting the rows' data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since version 3.35.0 (2021-03-12), SQLite includes a non-standard [RETURNING clause](https://sqlite.org/lang_returning.html) that allows for what you are looking for.
In your case, you would just write:

```sql
UPDATE "ACTIVE"
SET confirmed2 = '%d'
WHERE username2 = '%s' AND activity = '%d'
RETURNING *;
```

Comment: Weird. I have a simple counter table and when I do `UPDATE counter SET count = count + 1 RETURNING *;` it increments it by 3 instead of 1.

Comment: @Mike I tested your SQL. but increased exactly 1. `create table counter (user_id int not null, count int not null);
insert into counter select 1, 1 returning *;
insert into counter select 2, 2 returning *;
update counter set count = count + 1 returning *;`

Comment: @doctorgu I was probably doing something wrong in my code. Like maybe it was being executed in a loop. Who knows? This was over 2 years ago.

Answer (score 3):

The UPDATE statement does not return anything, so this is not possible.

Using a SELECT statement immediately afterwards does not hurt; the rows will still be in the cache.

Comment: Didn't know there was a cache! That explains what I thought was a total lack of sqlite3 functions.